# An issue with logic

Tags: java

I have a string `Str`, that I read from a file. Its values can be `null`, `"norw"` or `!="norw"`. Now I want to execute a code block when its value is either `null` or `!=norw`. How do I do that?

Comment: Some of the answrers don't work becouse you read the string from a file and can't use the opperator == you have to use equals() instead.

Comment: lol, do we have issues with any other things ?

Comment: If you have problems with this, you should start with a programming or java tutorial before anything else.

Comment: @Snicolas I have time constraints, I'm learning while I'm coding. Thanks for your help and sweet remarks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (str==null || !str.equals("norw")) {
  // do whatever
}
```

Comment: I would use `if (!"norw".equals(str)) { ... }` in that case. It handles the `null` case, and has the advantage to confuse the future readers of your code.

Comment: @Binoy What do you mean? The || operator is OR-ing the two conditions condition 1 is str==null and condition 2 is !str.equals("norw"). Implement this and test your program, it will work.

Comment: @Binoy If str is null then the first condition will be True and the second will never be evaluated. so you will never have to test on a null str for equality with 'norw'

Comment: @Binoy Great! Do mark the answer correct if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 5):

For strings you need to use [`equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438408/an-issue-with-logic/9438433#9438433) and not `operator==` [or `!=`] to check equality

```
if (!"norw".equals(str)) { ... }
```

(*)Note that for checking is `str` is `null` you do use `operator==` since you check identity.